# Firefox pop-up scam ads

Tags: malware

Since last week, when use ubunt, my firefox browser pop ups some scammy article links up left corner as it is shown in the image. So does that mean my computer is infected. And if it does, then how can I clean it? I used ClamTK, but it didnt find anyting.

[image]

Comment: Run these commands let me know what happens:  close firefox, open a terminal, run: `mv ~/.mozilla{,.bk}` open firefox see what happens do you still get the ads?

Comment: Add adblock to firefox - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/ . If that fails you can add a proxy server such as privoxy.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/

Comment: The above is a good suggestion but I would find the malware extension/add-on and simply uninstall it instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable all push notification in Mozilla Firefox via the main menu `Edit->Preferences->Content` then by `Notifications` click on `Choose` button to change settings of every site that sends you push notifications.

You don't have to install any add-ons or modify any file on your OS.

Check this screenshot: 
[image: Screenshot of allowed sites to send notifications]

For further information about Push Notifications in Mozilla Firefox:

[Control Center - manage site privacy and security controls](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/push-notifications-firefox)

Comment: I tried going to `about:preferences#content` and it was going straight to `about:prefrences#content`. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and FireFox 89.0 (64-bit).